# How do I filter URL given from speedtest-cli Linux

Tags: bash

I need your help again.

I've downloaded the speedtest-cli via apt-get on my Raspberry PI 3B (Running Raspbian Stretch with Kernel 4.14.81.v7+) because I want to monitor my network speed throughout the day(s).

Problem is the following: I want to get only the http:// address which `speedtest-cli --share` prints on the terminal. (I want to display the latest speedtest on my website) I tried

```
speedtest-cli --share | grep 'Share results: '
```

but it prints

```
Share results: http://www.speedtest.net/result/*********
```

instead of

```
http://www.speedtest.net/result/********
```

Also another question: I've written this code in an `crontab -e`:

`*/60 * * * * (date >> /home/pi/speedtest/speed.txt; /usr/bin/speedtest-cli --server 3645  --simple >> /home/pi/speedtest/speed.txt; echo "\n" >> /home/pi/speedtest/speed.txt)`
It hasn't printed something yet, is it correct?

Edit:

The standard output of `speedtest-cli --share` is sth. like that:

```
Retrieving speedtest.net configuration...
Testing from ISP (IP Address)...
Retrieving speedtest.net server list...
Selecting best server based on ping...
Hosted by Speedtest Provider (Location of ST Provider) [distance in km]: Ping
Testing download speed................................................................................
Download: ***.** Mbit/s
Testing upload speed....................................................................................................
Upload: ***.** Mbit/s
Share results: http://www.speedtest.net/result/***********.png
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve with `*/60` and a single `(`?

Comment: I want that it tests my speed every 60 Minutes and write it into a file called speed.txt in /home/pi/speedtest/

Comment: Replace `*/60` with `0` and wait until the hour is up.

Comment: I'll try that, thank you for your participation here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this with GNU grep:

```
speedtest-cli --share | grep -Po 'Share results: \K.*'
```

or

```
speedtest-cli --share 2>&1 | grep -Po 'Share results: \K.*'
```